# How to specify a printer?

Tags: print

The Emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Printing.html) says:

> `M-x` `print-buffer`
>
> Print hardcopy of current buffer with page headings containing the file name and page number.
>
> `M-x` `lpr-buffer`
>
> Print hardcopy of current buffer without page headings.
>
> `M-x` `print-region`
>
> Like `print-buffer` but print only the current region.
>
> `M-x` `lpr-region`
>
> Like `lpr-buffer` but print only the current region.
>
> [...]
>
> To specify the printer to use, set the variable `printer-name`. The default, `nil`, specifies the default printer.

How do we specify the printer to use?

For example, a PDF printer, which is not shown in the output of

```
lpstat -p -d
```

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to install `cups-pdf` package, then follow the instructions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS#PDF_virtual_printer (there isn't much to do, but be warned it is very likely that your user isn't allowed to print anything at all... CUPS is a fundamentally user-ugly system. So, you would need to log in as root (or find a way to make your user eligible for printer management, and no, it is not enough to be a sudoer). Then you can print just as you intended to. But (as I commented on your other question), PS and then `ps2pdf` will look nicer.

Answer (score 10):

If you are on Linux you can install [gtklp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtklp/) and set

```
(setq lpr-command "gtklp")
(setq ps-lpr-command "gtklp")
```

to give you a graphical print wizard. This doesn't actually give you print-to-file (unless you have a virtual pdf printer set up in CUPS), but it generally allows for easy printing from emacs.

Answer (score 3):

The printing happens to the printer name set in the environment variable `PRINTER`.

For example:

- I would first set the env var `PRINTER` to `my-printer`
- Then launch emacs in that terminal
- Then do `M-x ps-print-buffer-with-faces`

Comment: So you have to restart Emacs to select a different printer?

Comment: Ah, no: doing customize-apropos printer name lets you type in the name of the printer to use.

Comment: @Supernormal `printer-name` works if the user hasn't set the `PRINTER` env variable name, I believe, as per [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/printing.el?id=6d410fb03c53a892d2cf19238b15c5957ec1a7d8#n1936)... Note that the `PRINTER` env var gets the highest precedence.